# Get image from camera

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera

I am trying to get an image from the camera on an Android device. I want to display the image in an `ImageView`. I have a button in a fragment that opens the camera. I use the [Activity Results API](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) to get the response. Here's the fragment code:

```
class MainFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)

        val activity = requireActivity()
        val file = File(activity.filesDir,"images/go_capture.png")
        val imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            activity,
            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".images.provider",
            file
        )
        val takePicture = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()) { saved: Boolean ->
            Log.d(MainFragment::class.toString(), "take picture result")
            Log.d(MainFragment::class.toString(), saved.toString())
            val action = MainFragmentDirections.actionImage(imageUri.toString())
            view.findNavController().navigate(action)
        }

        val cameraButton: ImageButton = view.findViewById(R.id.camera_button)
        cameraButton.setOnClickListener {
            takePicture.launch(imageUri)
        }

        return view
    }
}
```

When I click on the button and take a picture, I get the following exception

```
Unable to open content: content://codeguru.cameraexample.images.provider/images/go_capture.png
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.openInternal(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:342)
    at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.open(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:229)
    at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.openFile(FileProvider.java:632)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.openAssetFile(ContentProvider.java:2026)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProvider.java:2202)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProvider.java:2269)
    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProvider.java:548)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:2027)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1842)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:1518)
    at android.graphics.ImageDecoder$ContentResolverSource.createImageDecoder(ImageDecoder.java:278)
    at android.graphics.ImageDecoder.decodeDrawableImpl(ImageDecoder.java:1766)
    at android.graphics.ImageDecoder.decodeDrawable(ImageDecoder.java:1759)
    at android.widget.ImageView.getDrawableFromUri(ImageView.java:1017)
    at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:986)
    at android.widget.ImageView.setImageURI(ImageView.java:561)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageURI(AppCompatImageView.java:132)
    at codeguru.cameraexample.ImageFragment.onCreateView(ImageFragment.kt:22)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:3104)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:524)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1899)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1823)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1760)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2985)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:2902)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:3171)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.start(FragmentStateManager.java:588)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:279)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:113)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1433)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2977)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:2902)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchStart(FragmentController.java:274)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:359)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:248)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1455)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8076)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3660)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2210)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    2022-11-05 11:01:30.720  3702-3702  ImageView               codeguru.cameraexample               W      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
2022-11-05 11:01:30.721  3702-3702  ImageView               codeguru.cameraexample               W  resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: content://codeguru.cameraexample.images.provider/images/go_capture.png
```

How do I fix this error? What am I missing?

Comment: Does the `images` directory in `getFilesDir()` exist already? I don't think `FileProvider` creates directories for you. If it does exist, did the camera app create your desired file in that directory?

Comment: @CommonsWare IDK...that's probably the problem. How do I check if the camera app created the directory or the file?

Comment: Use Device File Explorer in Android Studio, or the equivalent in other tools, to examine `getFilesDir()` for your app and see what's there.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks. Looks like it is called Device Explorer in the most recent version of AS.

Comment: I have Dolphin, and it is still Device File Explorer there, FWIW.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok. I am using Flamingo Canary. Looks like it changed. (And my claim of "most recent version" was imprecise.)

Comment: @CommonsWare Looks like the missing directory is indeed the problem. After creating it, everything works.

Comment: "(And my claim of "most recent version" was imprecise.)" -- I test enough of their stuff that I tend to avoid pre-release IDE versions, so from my standpoint, you're programming in the future. 

Comment: @CommonsWare I check out JetBrains EAP releases frequently. If I encounter any problems in the first few minutes, I'll close it and go back to the stable version until the next update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileProvider` will not create directories for you, even though it will create files for you in a designated directory. So, you should make sure that the directory for your file exists before anything tries using a `Uri` from `FileProvider` for that file.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I added a call to `File.mkdir()` in the fragment code from my question here. This doesn't quite feel like the right place for that, though. Any suggestions about a better place to put this? I thought maybe I should subclass `FileProvider` and do it there, but then I don't know if I have access to `activity.fileDirs`. (And maybe this should be a new question...)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: My typical answer here would be "in your viewmodel or repository", but I don't know your architecture.

Comment: ATM, I don't have a ViewModel. This app won't have a database. It will take the image of a board game and convert it into a text file which can be opened in a variety of apps that can read the particular file format.